# Excel VBA - validate is numeric and textlength

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to validate cells on a sheet in my Sub which will check to ensure it is a number and is no longer than the required textlength, this varies but I am finding this using a Function.

I can validate the text length but obviously this will still allow text:

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateTextLength, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:=ValidMaxLength
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that we want to count the number of round digits (not including decimal digits, minus sign or decimal points):

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
          Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=IF(" & Selection.Address & _
          "=0, TRUE, AND(ISNUMBER(" & Selection.Address & _
          "), ROUNDDOWN(LOG10(ABS(" _
          & Selection.Address & ")),0)<" & ValidMaxLength - 1 & "))"
End With
```

And this should do the work considering that 1eN has N+1 digits.

Comment: This isn't working in that I can add a huge number and it is just counting the number of characters in the field, rather than the length of the number

Comment: should add this is an issue when Excel changes the large number to    1E+nnn

Comment: I changed the approach to count number of digits even if it is in scientific format. I ignore decimal digits and minus sign as well.